# how to add a controller event to href in grid in extjs mvc

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

In my extjs grid 'cutterGrid' i have a renderer that has the following output

```
<a href="#" class="myclass">Product 1</a>
```

on my controller i have the following

```
    '#cutterGrid':{
        cellclick :this.onCutterSelectRow
    },
```

This works but, obviously this enables click on the whole row. I just  want this on a particular cell.

Here is the field in  my grid

```
 {
                            xtype:'gridcolumn',
                            dataIndex:'CutterNumber',
                            text:'Cutter',
                            renderer: renderCutter,
                            flex:1,
                            sortable: true
                        },
```

Comment: What version of ExtJs are you using? If it's 4 - add tag `extjs4`, 3 - `extjs3` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cellclick event passes several parameters to your function - one of them is EventObject

```
cellclick( Ext.view.Table this, HTMLElement td, Number cellIndex, Ext.data.Model record, HTMLElement tr, Number rowIndex, Ext.EventObject e, Object eOpts )
```

In your function, you should be able to do this:

```
function onCutterSelectRow(table, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts)
{
    var target = e.getTarget();
    //test HtmlElement target to be your anchor, by class name and element.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem with subscribing to the `ahref` events is you need to wait until HTML element is rendered and only then subscribe to it. When I had a link on my form that I need to listen to I did something like this:

```
{
   xtype: 'box',
   autoEl: '<a href='#'>Link</a>',
   listeners: {
      render: function(e) {
         e.getEl().down('a').on('click', function() {
            console.log('GOTCHA!');
         }, e);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i see your point. ideally i would subscribe to the cell and use "cellclick " but i'm not sure how to filter out the whole row in my controller. In regards to your example above how can i do this within the mvc paradigm

Comment: Well... this code presumable would be in your view, right? You can replace `console.log` with `fireEvent()` and then subscribe to this event in the controller.